# How is list.clear() different from list = []?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The intended objective of function `foo` is to add the number provided as argument to the list and, in case it is 0, reset the list. First I wrote this program:

```
def foo(n, bar = []):
    if n == 0:
        bar = []
        print("list empty")
    else:
        bar.append(n)
        for y in bar:
            print(y, end=', ')
        print()

foo(5)
foo(3)
foo(0)
foo(6)
```

output:

```
5, 
5, 3, 
list empty
5, 3, 6,
```

but it looks like `bar = []` is ignored. Then I changed `bar = []` with `bar.clear()` and it works as I thought:

```
def foo(n, bar = []):
    if n == 0:
        bar.clear()
        print("list empty")
    else:
        bar.append(n)
        for y in bar:
            print(y, end=', ')
        print()

foo(5)
foo(3)
foo(0)
foo(6)
```

output:

```
5, 
5, 3, 
list empty
6,
```

I haven't understood why `bar.clear()` works differntly from `bar = []` since `clear()` should

> Remove all elements from the set.

so the same thing `bar = []` does.

**Edit:** I don't think my question is a duplicate of [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), I'm aware that

> The default value is evaluated only once.

(from the official tutorial) but what I am asking is, why `bar = []` doesn't edit (in this case clear) the list, while append and clear does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: `l.clear()` is the equivalent of `l[:] = []`, not `l = []`.  You're mutating an existing list object instead of creating a new empty list.

Comment: `bar = foo[]` isn't used in your code, as far as I can see, so it's not there to be ignored.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Super pedantic, but `l.clear()` is most directly equivalent to `del l[:]`. `l[:] = []` requires the creation of a temporary `list`, `del l[:]` doesn't. Admittedly, the distinction is fairly irrelevant to observed behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bar = []` *rebinds* `bar`; it creates a brand new empty `list`, and binds the name `bar` to it. It doesn't matter what `bar` was before; it could have been an `int`, a `tuple`, or `dict`, and it's irrelevant now, because it's now bound to a brand new `list`. The old binding no longer exists in the current method call, but the original `list` [remains in existence as the value of the default argument to `foo`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/364696) (note: Mutable defaults are considered surprising and ugly because of this confusion).

`bar.clear()` calls a method on the *existing* `list`, which tells that `list` to clear itself (and has no effect on what `bar` refers to; it better be *something* with a `clear` method, but other than that, it's not really required that it be a `list`). Since it's the *same* `bar` you started with (referencing the same mutable default value cached in the function defaults), that affects your future calls (because `bar` continues to refer to the `list` you provided as the mutable default).

Answer (score 4):

The thing you should really understand is how variables work in Python.

The variables are always just references to the actual content. Nothing is stored in the variable itself it just points to the unnamed content.

Now, when you call `foo()` what you have is a list in memory and the local `bar` variable is pointing to that. If you call `bar.clear()`, that list is actually cleared and that's what you want. However, if you say `bar = []` you just bind the local `bar` variable to a new, empty list and the other list (that already contains 5 and 3) remains intact and it will be used the next time you call `foo()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here in you code `bar` is the reference to some list located in memory. 
When you use `bar = []`, the variable `bar` becomes associated with a new (empty) list. When you use  `bar.clear()`, you modify current list.

Speaking generally, this means that lists in Python are passed by reference and not by value. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/747744).

Answer (score 3):

When you do a `list.clear()`, the list gets cleared :-)
When you do a `list = []`, the list gets overwritten by a new empty list.

The difference is that if something was referencing the list before if was overwritten, it will still be referencing the values you think now has been cleared.

This is an excellent way of introducing extremely hard to debug bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a list containing some values, and you assign it to a variable named foo.

```
foo = [0, 1]
```

This variable now points to this list in memory.

Let's say you then create a new variable named bar and assign to foo.

```
bar = foo
```

These two variables now point to the same list object in memory. If you then change foo and have it equal [], what happens to bar?

```
foo = []
bar == [0, 1] # True
```

Now let's do the same with foo.clear().

```
foo.clear()
bar == [] # True
```

This is because using the clear method on a list clears that list object, which affects everything that references this object, while assigning a variable to an empty list only changes what that variables, and doesn't change the original list whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

this has desired property:

```
def foo(n, bar = []):

    if n == 0:
        bar[:] = []
        print("list empty")
    else:
        bar.append(n)
        for y in bar:
            print(y, end=', ')
        print()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, just provide an alternate way of writing the "working" code (which `bar.clear()` already covers adequately). It's fine to provide fixed code, but you need to explain *why* it's better/more correct than the original.